# Can quantum algorithms be used for encryption?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, wep

Can quantum algorithms be useful?

Has any one been successful in putting quantum algorithms to any use?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_cryptography

Comment: Is this really a programming question?

Comment: For those doing quantum computing research it is.  And research sometimes moves into mainstream.

Comment: My understanding is that there is still a large amount of software development needed to exploit the inherent quantum capabilities of quantum computing.  The current small set of applications are noted by ShreevatsaR.  So I think this is a programming related Q.

Answer (score 7):

"Quantum algorithms" are algorithms to be run on quantum computers.

There are things that can be done quickly in the quantum computation model that are not known (or believed) to be possible with classical computation: [Discrete logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) and [Integer factorisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) (see [Shor's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm)) are in [BQP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BQP), but not believed to be in P (or [BPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BPP)). Thus when/if a quantum computer is built, it is known that it can break RSA and most current cryptography.

However,

- quantum computers cannot (are not believed to, I mean) solve NP-complete problems in polynomial time, and more importantly,
- no one has built a quantum computer yet, and it is not even clear if it will be possible to build one -- avoiding decoherence, etc. (There have been claims of quantum computers with a limited number of qubits -- 5 to 10, but clearly they are not useful for anything much.)

> "Well, there's a quantum computer that can factor 15, so those of you using
> 4-bit RSA should worry." -- Bruce Schneier

[There is also the idea of *quantum cryptography*, which is cryptography over a quantum channel, and is something quite different from quantum computation.]

Comment: BTW, I should repeat: [quantum cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_cryptography) is something else entirely, which has nothing to do with quantum algorithms or quantum computation. It involves using quantum physics to set up a **physically** secure channel to share keys.

Answer (score 6):

The only logical answer is that they are both useful and not useful. ;-)

Comment: Heisenberg probably was here!

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that current quantum computing capabilities can be used to exchange keys securely.  The exchanged keys can then be used to perform traditional cryptography.

Comment: What you have in mind is quantum cryptography, but it uses quantum physics directly ("physically"), and does not use / relate to quantum computing.

Answer (score 2):

As far i know about Quantum Computing and Algorithms.I seen pretty much usage of Quantum Algorithms in Cryptography.If you are really interested in Cryptography do please check on those things.Basically all matter is how well you know basics of Quantum mechanics and discrete mathematics. Eg: you must be seeing difficult algorithms like Shor's Algorithm ,this basically integer factorization.Basically integer factorization is easy thing using normal algorithms Algebraic-group factorization algorithm,Fermat's factorization method..etc but when its comes to Quantum Computing its totally different,you are running the things in Quantum computers so algorithm changes and we have to use the algorithms like Shor's etc.

Basically make good understanding about Quantum Computing and then look Quantum Algorithms

Answer (score 0):

There is also some research into whether quantum computing can be used to solve hard problems, such as factoring large numbers (if this was feasible it would break current encryption techniques).

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow runs on a quantum computer of sorts.

Feynman has implied the possibility that quantum probability is the source of human creativity.

Individuals in the crowd present answers and vote on them with only a probability of being correct.  Only by sampling the crowd many times can the probability be raised to a confident level.

So maybe Stackoverflow examplifies a successful quantum algorithm implementation.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

One good use of a quantum device that can be done in current technology is a random number generator.

Generating truly random bits is an important cryptographic primitive, and is used, for example, in the RSA algorithm to generate the private key. In our PC the random number generator isn't random at all in the sense that the source has no entropy in it, and therefore isn't really random at all.